# Handle cleanup action error in slick dbio actions

Tags: scala, exception, slick

I have the below scenario and I am trying to use the slick DBIO actions to achieve it.

```
Execute a batch Insert operation. On success, return the inserted result On failure,
          -> if the failure is due to duplicate value in a particular column, then remove the duplicates from the list, and try batch insert again. If the second batch insert is successful, return a successful future with the second inserted list, else the failed future of the 2nd batch insert.
          -> if the failure is due to something else, then throw that exception
```

For the above scenario, I tried using the cleanUp action. But, I do not know how to return the cleanUp actions result if the main action fails.

How can I achieve my requirement using DBIO Actions Error handling ?

```
def insertBatchAndReturnQuery(rowList: List[E]): FixedSqlAction[Seq[E], NoStream, Write] = {
    query returning query ++= rowList
 }


def insert(entities: List[E]): Future[Seq[E]] = {
    val q = insertBatchAndReturnQuery(entities).cleanUp {
      case Some(ex) => ex match {
        case b: PSQLException => {
          if (b.getSQLState.equals("23505")) {
            //unique key exception, handle this by removing the duplicate entries from the list
            ???
          } else {
            throw new Exception("some database exception")
          }
        }
      }
      case None => insertBatchAndReturnQuery(Nil)
    }
    db.run(q)
  }
```

> Here, query is TableQuery[T].

Slick Version : 3.2.0-M2

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the signature for `cleanUp` that it returns an action with value of the same type as the first action, so there is no way you'll be able to return the value from the cleanUp action.

If you wish to return the second value, you need to wrap your error in a `Try`, using `asTry`, and then use `flatMap`. For the problem at hand, it would look something like this:

```
val q = insertBatchAndReturnQuery(entities).asTry.flatMap {
  case Failure(b: PSQLException) if b.getSQLState == "23505" =>
    //unique key exception, handle this 
    //by removing the duplicate entries from the list
    ???
  case Failure(e) =>
    throw new Exception("some database exception")
  case Success(count) => DBIO.successful(count)
}
```

However the documentation warns that using `asTry` loses streaming capacity, so you may want to find another way to do this...